# Что означает данная команда?

Tags: c#, sql

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Users";
```

Comment: На этом сайте найдете всю нужную информацию для ознакомления с курсом SQL Возможно поможет: https://metanit.com/sql/mysql/1.1.php

Answer (score 4):

string - тип переменной (string переводиться как строка, т.е. какой то текст в перменной)

sql - название переменной

SELECT * FROM Users  - значение твоей переменной.

Читай документацию. это же элементарные вопросы